# Linear Optimization code Python using Pulp

Tags: python

The problem I need is to solve, is a linear optimization problem where we need to to minimize parcel delivery costs by assigning nodes as hubs, which supposedly will reduce costs.

In my code 'nodes' represents the number of nodes of a given set N. Then 'flows' is a list with the flow x_{ij} from a node i to a node j. In a similar way the list 'costs' is established. 'estab' is a list with the fixed costs f_i for establishing a hub.

A route from node i to node j is given by the sum of (chi*costs(i,k)+alpha*costs(k,l)+delta*costs(l,j), where there are indeed three parts: collection, transfer and distribution.

The problem it-self is solved. The implementation, however, is the issue. Firstly, running this gives 'UserWarning: Overwriting previously set objective'. Secondly, the result is that every node is assigned as a hub, which seems unlikely.

Thanks in advance!

```
from pulp import *

nodes = range(10)

flows = [[75,37,55,19,20,18,57,17,19,16],
        [26,38,25,27,18,23,38,20,12,17],
        [67,39,51,22,24,21,71,20,23,19],
        [17,33,19,25,16,23,40,23,11,19],
        [17,25,21,19,23,18,73,20,24,19],
        [12,18,12,16,11,17,37,22,10,18],
        [82,78,90,68,95,73,312,99,110,110],
        [35,42,36,48,36,58,173,90,41,92],
        [12,12,15,10,19,11,68,15,24,20],
        [22,25,23,28,23,33,109,51,30,63]]

costs = [[0,20,16,23,23,30,32,33,36,36],
        [20,0,20,13,25  ,19,30,25,38,31],
        [16,20,0,14,7,19,16,18,21,21],
        [23,13,14,0,14,7,18,13,27,18],
        [23,25,7,14,0,16,9,13,14,14],
        [30,19,19,7,16,0,16,8,25,13],
        [32,30,16,18,9,16,0,9,10,7],
        [33,25,18,13,13,8,9,0,18,5],
        [36,38,21,27,14,25,10,18,0,14],
        [36,31,21,18,14,13,7,5,14,0]]

estab = [28767,28377,29774,24301,25853,20763,34166,33859,24718,33686]

chi = 3              #multiplier costs of collection
alpha = 1            #multiplier costs of transfer
delta = 2            #multiplier costs of distribution

estab_dict = dict(zip(nodes,estab))

Parcdelco = LpProblem('Parcdelco', LpMinimize)

con = LpVariable.dicts('Connection', (nodes,nodes),0,1,LpInteger)

routes = [(i,k,l,j) for i in nodes for k in nodes for l in nodes for j in nodes]


path = LpVariable.dicts('Path', (nodes,nodes,nodes,nodes),0,1,LpInteger)

for i in nodes:
    for j in nodes:
        Parcdelco += lpSum([flows[i][j]*lpSum([path[i][k][l][j]*(chi*costs[i][k]+alpha*costs[k][l]+delta*costs[l][j]) for (i,k,l,j) in routes])])\
                    +lpSum([con[i][i]*estab_dict[i] for i in nodes])

for i in nodes:
    Parcdelco += lpSum([con[i][i]]) >= 1

for i in nodes:
    for j in nodes:
        Parcdelco += lpSum([con[i][j]]) == 1

for i in nodes:
    for k in nodes:
        Parcdelco += con[i][k] <= con[k][k]

for i in nodes:
    for k in nodes:
        for l in nodes:
            for j in nodes:
                Parcdelco += path[i][k][l][j] <= con[i][k] + con[j][l]

for i in nodes:
    for k in nodes:
        for l in nodes:
            for j in nodes:
                Parcdelco += path[i][k][l][j] >= (1/2)*(con[i][k] + con[j][l] - 1)



Parcdelco.solve()

for i in nodes:
    print(value(con[i][i]))
```

Comment: "Secondly, the result is that every node is assigned as a hub, which seems unlikely." So the output is likely incorrect? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].